# SwiftUI: Timer with start and stop not working

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, timer

I have to animate after every 10 secs and I'm using `Timer.publish` and trying to **stop** timer if I push to another screen and **start again** timer on pops back to the same screen.

But even after `cancel()`, I can see logs in the `sink` method. Let me know the correct way to handle it.

```
struct MyView: View {
   
    @StateObject private var viewModel = QRCodeScanViewModel()
   
    var body: some View {
      parentView
         .onAppear {
            viewModel.playPulseAnimation()
         }
         .onDisappear(perform: viewModel.removePulseAnimation)
    }
}
```

```
final class MyAnimationClass: ObservableObject {
    
    private(set) var timer = Timer.publish(every: 10, tolerance: 0.5, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    
    @Published var shouldPlayPulseAnimation = false

    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    init() {
     ..
     ...

        timer
            .sink(receiveValue: { [weak self] _ in
                print("TIMER SINK")
                self?.shouldPlayPulseAnimation = true
            })
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }

    func playPulseAnimation(isFirstTime: Bool = false) {
        let delay: DispatchTime = .now() + (isFirstTime ? 15 : 0)
        print("playPulseAnimation:", delay)
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: delay) { [weak self] in
            guard let this = self else {
                return
            }
            this.timer = Timer.publish(every: 10, tolerance: 0.5, on: .main, in: .default).autoconnect()
        }
    }

    func removePulseAnimation() {
        print("removePulseAnimation")
        shouldPlayPulseAnimation = false
        timer.upstream.connect().cancel()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the cancellable.

```
func removePulseAnimation() {
    print("removePulseAnimation")
    shouldPlayPulseAnimation = false
    timer.upstream.connect().cancel()
    cancellables.removeAll()
}
```

Given you would need to subscribe back the Timer's publisher. You would also need. The following change in View Model. It can't be in init, given may not be called again when you come back to view again

```
init() {
   
}

func subscribeToTimer() {
    timer
        .sink(receiveValue: { [weak self] _ in
            print("TIMER SINK")
            self?.shouldPlayPulseAnimation = true
        })
        .store(in: &cancellables)
}
```

In OnAppear of the view, something like this.

```
onAppear{
            viewModel.subscribeToTimer()
            viewModel.playPulseAnimation()
        }
```

Please be careful, you may be holding many subscriptions as cancellable is a set. All subscriptions will be unsubscribed by doing removeAll.

Comment: Normally when you navigate to Page B from Page A , you should call cancellables.removeAll(), if there is nothing real time going on in the page A. But let say its a chatting application and you clicked to read a thread. You won't like to cancellables.removeAll() in Chat thread page because you need to listen to any incoming thread even when you are reading a chat of someone.